# Найти ближайшее число из массива

Tags: php, массивы, веб-программирование, php7, сравнение

Есть массив и переменная:

```
$array = array(2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512);

$count = 47;
```

Как проверить к какому числу из массива переменная ближе, **при этом она должна быть больше или равна выбранному числу из массива**. Массив статический.

То есть, если число 120, то должно вывести 64, а не 128

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С использованием map_reduce():

```
<?php
$array = array(2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512);
$count = 31;

echo array_reduce($array, function ($carry, $item) use ($count) {
    return $item <= $count? max($carry, $item): $carry;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение:

```
<?php

$array = array(2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512);
$count = 31;
arsort($array);
foreach($array as $key){
if($key <= $count){
echo "Result: $key";
exit;
}
}
```

Comment: а смысл гонять два цикла если можно одним?

Comment: на кой сортировать массив  в обратном порядке, если можно перебирать с конца?

Comment: зачем вообще сортировать, если можно перебирать и запоминать наиболее подходящее

Comment: Зачем предлагать иное решение, если можно критиковать существующее?

Answer (score 0):

Closest to the value from the array by parameter. And do not forget about the value less than the minimum value in the array 8 [12, 23, 55]

```
$result = array_reduce($array, function ($carry, $item) use ($params) {
      return abs($carry["D"] - $params["D"]) >= abs($item["D"] - $params["D"]) ? $item : $carry;
    });
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст ответа (нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа) на русский язык